# Implicitly declared function error C++

Tags: c++

I'm having an issue compiling my C++ file.
This is the error I get:

Multiple markers at this line
    - Member declaration not found
    - definition of implicitly-declared 'InsultGenerator::InsultGenerator(const InsultGenerator&)'

I'm using MinGW as my compiler.

Here is the C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Insultgenerator_0hl14.h"

using namespace std;

FileException::FileException(const string& m) : message(m){}

string& FileException::what(){ return message;}

NumInsultsOutOfBounds::NumInsultsOutOfBounds(const string& m) : message(m){}

string& NumInsultsOutOfBounds::what(){ return message;}

InsultGenerator::InsultGenerator(const InsultGenerator& ) {}

void InsultGenerator::initialize() const{
int cols(0);
string x;

string filename("InsultsSource.txt");
ifstream file(filename.c_str());

if(file.fail()){
    throw FileException("File not read.");
}
 while(file >> x){

 }}

//vector<string> InsultGenerator::talkToMe() const{

  //    };//end talkToMe

  //    vector<string> InsultGenerator::generate(const int n) const{

   //   };//end generate

//int InsultGenerator::generateAndSave(const string filename, const int n)           const{

//};//end generateAndSave
```

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef INSULTGENERATOR_0HL14_H_
#define INSULTGENERATOR_0HL14_H_

#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class InsultGenerator{
public:
InsultGenerator(vector<string>);
void initialize() const;
string talkToMe() const;
vector<string> generate(const int) const;
int generateAndSave (const string, const int) const;

private:
vector<string> colA;
vector<string> colB;
vector<string> colC;
};

class FileException{
public:
FileException(const string&);
string& what();
private:
string message;
};

class NumInsultsOutOfBounds{
public:
NumInsultsOutOfBounds(const string &);
string& what();
private:
string message;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Could you provide the full error text?

Comment: here it is Multiple markers at this line
 - Member declaration not found
 - definition of implicitly-declared 'InsultGenerator::InsultGenerator(const InsultGenerator&)'

Comment: What was the last change you made before you saw this error? Is this [the simplest code that produces the error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: is it me or are you just not declaring InsultGenerator copy contructor?

Comment: Where is the question ??!?

Comment: Please do not deface your own question.

Answer (score 4):

You are implementing `InsultGenerator`'s copy-constructor although you haven't declared it.

Add `InsultGenerator(const InsultGenerator& );` to your `InsultGenerator` class.
Like so:

```
class InsultGenerator
{
public:
    InsultGenerator(vector<string>); // also better remove that one since I don't
                                     // think you have implemented it

    InsultGenerator(const InsultGenerator &); // here
    void initialize() const;
    string talkToMe() const;
    vector<string> generate(const int) const;
    int generateAndSave (const string, const int) const;
private:
    vector<string> colA;
    vector<string> colB;
    vector<string> colC;
};
```

Comment: how do i declare it? Sorry, i am not very knowledgeable in C++

Comment: would i still need the InsultGenerator(vector<string>); constructor?

Comment: @harmanlitt If you're going to construct it from a `vector<string>` object, then yes. Right now, that constructor is declared but not defined or used. You just have to declare member functions before defining them out-of-class, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
   class InsultGenerator
    {
    public:
        InsultGenerator(vector<string>); // Remove this line.
        InsultGenerator(const InsultGenerator &); // Add this line.
        void initialize() const;
        string talkToMe() const;
     ......
    }
```