# C++ "No matching function for call" error

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw

I'm using MinGW compiler. I don't understand why I am getting an error.

**Error :**

```
Multiple markers at this line
- candidate is:
- no matching function for call to 'InsultGenerator::InsultGenerator()'
- Line breakpoint: Insultgenerator_0hl14.cpp [line: 22]
```

Here is the cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Insultgenerator_0hl14.h"

using namespace std;

FileException::FileException(const string& m) : message(m){}

string& FileException::what(){ return message;}

NumInsultsOutOfBounds::NumInsultsOutOfBounds(const string& m) : message(m){}

string& NumInsultsOutOfBounds::what(){ return message;}

InsultGenerator::InsultGenerator(const InsultGenerator& ) {}

void InsultGenerator::initialize() const{
    int cols(0);
    InsultGenerator t1;
    string insults;

    string filename("InsultsSource.txt");
    ifstream file(filename.c_str());

    if(file.fail()){
        throw FileException("File not read.");
    }
     while(file >> insults){
         if(cols==0){
            t1.colA.push_back(insults);
            cols++;
         } else if(cols==1){
             t1.colB.push_back(insults);
             cols++;
         }else{
             t1.colC.push_back(insults);
             cols= cols -2;
         }


     }
for (int i=0;i<50;i++){
    cout << i << t1.colA[i];
}

}
```

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef INSULTGENERATOR_0HL14_H_
#define INSULTGENERATOR_0HL14_H_

#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class InsultGenerator{
public:
//  InsultGenerator(vector<string>);
    InsultGenerator(const InsultGenerator &);
    void initialize() const;
    string talkToMe() const;
    vector<string> generate(const int) const;
    int generateAndSave (const string, const int) const;

private:
    vector<string> colA;
    vector<string> colB;
    vector<string> colC;
};

class FileException{
public:
    FileException(const string&);
    string& what();
private:
    string message;
};

class NumInsultsOutOfBounds{
public:
    NumInsultsOutOfBounds(const string &);
    string& what();
private:
    string message;
};

#endif
```

Comment: This code look very similar to [Implicitly declared function error C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28206954/1708801) although perhaps not the same issue.

Comment: Yes, that is my friend's file. We're working on the same project. We both currently have this error though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one Constructor for `InsultGenerator`: `InsultGenerator(const InsultGenerator &);`, but it has parameters. You need a Constructor without parameters, so the statement `InsultGenerator t1;` can call the corresponding Constructor correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Because you not have contructor for `InsultGenerator` object.
in header file, you add `InsultGenerator();` and in cpp file, you add

```
InsultGenerator::InsultGenerator() { }
```